# I'm completely stumped as to which Android Adapter to inherit/use

Tags: android, list, arraylist, adapter, feed

I have a data-structure which is of type:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
```

...It contains a set of elements of a news feed; each element is itself a list of fields and each field is a tuple(key:value) where both key&value are of type String.

NOTE: the reason fields are stored in ArrayList is I don't always know how many the feed-parser will spurt out.

The view:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:text="@string/news_and_events"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="245dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <!--FEED-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The row-template I want to use is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription=""
    />

<!--STARTING WITH title-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see there are 3-fields: title, body, image (a news feed).

So I'm completely stumped as to what type of adapter I should use.
All the ones' I've looked at don't seem to match what I want to do; specifically because of the data-structure I'm using.

Perhaps I should use a cursor adapter?
If so, how would I map this into a Relational-database?!

Comment: I'd recommend implementing your own Adapter. It's not that difficult. 
Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
There a tons of examples out there, how to implement a custom adapter.

Comment: Inherit from ArrayAdapter and let the data layer parse your objects, not the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using a `BaseAdapter`, it's the most flexible adapter Android has(I think)...
By doing so, you can implement a custom Adapter, which goes thru the `ArrayList`(using 2 cycles for extracting) and then parsing it to the visual components you specified.
Since it's constructor receives the context, the view and the data, you'll have the `ImageView` and so, there.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but I agree that `BaseAdapter` should be used. It is also flexible in terms of the data source, so it can be changed to pull from a database if needed rather than always relying on `ArrayList`.